# Authentication codeigniter-restserver

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, digest

I am having trouble with authentication in codeigniter-restserver.

When I set the config: `$config['rest_auth']` to either `basic` or `digest`, I can't seem to get through the validation, using the standard logins.

Is there anything else I need to take into account?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must populate the allowed username and passwords in **/application/config/rest.php** :

```
$config['rest_valid_logins'] = array('user1' => 'password');
```

Answer (score 0):

For basic, to work you need rest_auth to basic in your **/application/config/rest.php**

`$config['rest_auth'] = 'basic';`

then set username and password in the same file, to do this go to rest_valid_logins configuration in your **/application/config/rest.php** and set the key as the username and set the password as the value for that key. Remember it's an associate array so you can use multiple value key pairs.

`$config['rest_valid_logins'] = ['admin' => '1234'];`

Then make a call using HTTP basic authentication. To do that use the following format:
`https://username:password@domain/path/to/api`

For example, it could be
`https://admin:1234@localhost/api/users`